# How should I handle exceptions raised in @jwt_required decorator? (in flask-jwt-extended)

Tags: python, jwt, flask-jwt-extended

I have a function with @jwt_required decorator.

```
class Test(Resource):
    @jwt_required
    def get(self):
        return {"test": "ok" }
```

Which works fine when the correct HTTP header is set, i.e.

`Authentication: Bearer [TOKEN]`

but when the token is invalid/wrong or messed with, a jwt.exceptions.DecodeError is raised:

```
File "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restplus/resource.py", line 44, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py", line 103, in wrapper
    verify_jwt_in_request()
  File "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py", line 32, in verify_jwt_in_request
    jwt_data = _decode_jwt_from_request(request_type='access')
  File "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py", line 267, in _decode_jwt_from_request
    decoded_token = decode_token(encoded_token, csrf_token)
  File "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/utils.py", line 80, in decode_token
    encoded_token, verify=False, algorithms=config.algorithm
  File "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 84, in decode
    payload, _, _, _ = self._load(jwt)
  File "env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 183, in _load
    raise DecodeError('Not enough segments')
jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Not enough segments
```

I cannot rely on clients always using correct tokens all the time.
And I cannot catch the exception because it is raised in the decorator rather than my own function. So the result is a http 500 error. How should I handle the exception more gracefully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flask-jwt-extended should be handling those for you gracefully. If not, you are probably using another extension (like flask-restful for example) that is breaking native flask functionality. You can try setting this option to fix it `app.config[‘PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS’] = True`, or take a look at this thread for some advice if you are using a different flask extension that is causing problems https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/issues/86

Comment: thanks vimalloc, I am indeed using flask-restplus. Adding `jwt._set_error_handler_callbacks(api)` seems to do the trick for me!

Comment: @user1005265 I’m not having any luck on mine with it, where did you add jwt._set_error ?